# UDF in Azure Stream Analytics outputs alias in the JSON

Tags: azure-stream-analytics

Sript in SAJ:

```
SELECT 

udf.createJsonMessage(param1, param2)

INTO Output
FROM  EventHubLocal  eventHub
```

Removed other stuff as not needed here.

The UDF:

```
function CreateJsonMessageForOutput(param1, param2) {
    var obj = new Object();
    obj.Prop1 = param1;
    obj.Prop2 = param2;

    return JSON.stringify(obj);
}
```

Removed code as not needed here.

The output JSON includes the function alias:

```
{
"createjsonmessage": "{\"Prop1\":\"param1\",\"Prop2\":\"param2\"}"
}
```

What do I do to get it in this format:

```
{
    \"Prop1\":\"param1\",
    \"Prop2\":\"param2\"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible way to do that will be to extract the different elements from the object.
See an example below:

```
WITH step1 AS(
            SELECT udf.createJsonMessage(param1, param2)
            FROM EventHubLocal eventHub
)
SELECT createJsonMessage.Prop1, createJsonMessage.Prop2
INTO Output
FROM step1
```

This will just require a small change in the UDF function:

```
function CreateJsonMessageForOutput(param1, param2) {
  var obj = new Object();
  obj.Prop1 = param1;
  obj.Prop2 = param2;

  return obj;
}
```

Thanks,
JS

Answer (score 0):

To get value for a JSON object we can also use [GetRecordPropertyValue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/reference/getrecordpropertyvalue-azure-stream-analytics) method. where the property name as string expression.

This UDF function will return JSON object

```
function CreateJsonMessageForOutput(param1, param2) {
  var obj = new Object();
  obj.Prop1 = param1;
  obj.Prop2 = param2;
  return obj;
}
```

Query

```
WITH step1 AS(SELECT udf.createJsonMessage(param1, param2)
            FROM EventHubLocal eventHub)
SELECT GetRecordPropertyValue(createJsonMessage,'Prop1') as Prop1, GetRecordPropertyValue(createJsonMessage,'Prop2') as Prop2
INTO Output
FROM step1
```